# Inner join query returning all NULL result when it should return no result

Tags: mysql

This query is returning 1 record with all `NULL` values when there should not be a result. When there should be a result it seems to return fine.

I use inner joins to grab some account details and ratings using their table primary keys. Some of the non-primary (many to one) keys have default of NULL - maybe this causes it to join on itself somehow?

Why is it returning a row with all null values?

```
SELECT a.account_id, a.first_name, a.second_name, a.points, c.body, c.creation_time, AVG(t.rating_overall)
FROM comments AS c
INNER JOIN accounts AS a
ON c.account_id=a.account_id
INNER JOIN ratings AS t
ON t.blogger_id=a.account_id
WHERE c.blog_id = ?
ORDER BY c.creation_time ASC"
```

Comment: try using something like `ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )` just make the replacement value blank or 0

Comment: Sorry ill change my q I meant some keys not primary

Comment: The AVG field is probably the cause. I think it has given you a row with the average of all the fields, even when there are no fields to average.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using outer joins or something in the actual query you're sending? The query you posted can't return a row with all fields set to null, because `null = null` on the join condition would eliminate them.

Comment: That is the query I am using. I try it in the console with different blog_id and it either returns some comments or 1 row with NULL NULL NULL etc

Comment: Also there is no group by for the AVG(), please review the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you are using an aggregate function (AVG). This is going to give you a single row (in the abscence of a GROUP BY clause), even with no actual matching rows.

Try this:-

```
SELECT a.account_id, a.first_name, a.second_name, a.points, c.body, c.creation_time, AVG(t.rating_overall)
FROM comments AS c
INNER JOIN accounts AS a
ON c.account_id=a.account_id
INNER JOIN ratings AS t
ON t.blogger_id=a.account_id
WHERE c.blog_id = ?
GROUP BY a.account_id, a.first_name, a.second_name, a.points, c.body, c.creation_time
ORDER BY c.creation_time ASC
```

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0010 sec )  THANK YOOOU!! ;x